# I accidentally uninstalled the kingroot app and I can't find a way to completely unroot now

Tags: uninstallation

So all the sudden after having my phone rooted for a month, my phone freaked out and sent me a notification that said kingroot was "hurting" my phone. So I tried to click on it and apparently I hit the uninstall button in the notification and now I can't completely unroot to reroot and fix this. I can't just install another root and I've looked thru all of my files in the preinstalled "my files* app and there is nothing kingroot related if I understand correctly. Help pleeeaasee! Without root my battery is very bad and every stupid bloatware app autostarts.

Comment: Have you tried flashing the latest OFFICIAL ROM?

Answer (score 1):

just go to kingo root webiste and root again: https://www.kingoapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it again and then removing root, but UNTICK the KEEP BACKUP checkbox.